# Custom column to represent order

Tags: mysql, row-number

I am using MySQL to return columns from a data table. What I want to do is use Order By to order the results by a date fields in ascending order and then also return a custom column along with the other desired columns where the custom column represents the index in relation to the Order By results. Right, I have the following query which just returns the desired columns and orders the results:

```
SELECT
    `alert_id`,
    `message`,
    `expiration`
FROM
    `alert`
WHERE
    `is_active` = TRUE
ORDER BY
    `expiration`
```

But what I'm having difficulty with is how to also return the custom column that represents the order. So for example, I would like the following (sample data) rows returned:

```
  Pior to Order and Custom Column           After the Order and Custom Column
+----------+---------+------------+  +----------+---------+------------+----------+
| alert_id | message | expiration |  | alert_id | message | expiration | order_by |
+----------+---------+------------+  +----------+---------+------------+----------+
|    1     |  alert1 | 2017-11-20 |  |    5     |  alert5 | 2017-11-16 |     1    |
|    5     |  alert5 | 2017-11-16 |  |    6     |  alert6 | 2017-11-17 |     2    |
|    6     |  alert6 | 2017-11-17 |  |    1     |  alert1 | 2017-11-20 |     3    |
+----------+---------+------------+  +----------+---------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: Note: `TRUE` is just an alias for `1`, there's no real boolean values in MySQL.

Comment: What you are looking for is what is called ROW_NUMBER() in SQLServer and Oracle. You will find lots of questions here in stackoverflow if you search with that keyword.

Comment: @AdriánE - While the ROW_NUMBER function is not available in MySQL, I was able to emulate it by declaring a variable and then incrementing it in the SELECT statement. Thank you so much.

Comment: @David It's worth adding your solution as a self-answer to clarify what you mean by that. Someone else can benefit from that knowledge sharing, and that person might even be you in a year or two when you've forgotten.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `ROW_NUMBER()` function (and many others) is available in MySQL 8.0.3: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html I'm sure you're not using MySQL 8.0 yet, since it's currently in Release Candidate status, but it's something to look forward to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AdrianE's assistance in mentioning the ROW_NUMBER function, even though I am using MySQL and that function is not available, I was able to emulate the function by using the following:

```
SET @order = 0;
SELECT
    `alert_id`,
    `message`,
    DATE_FORMAT(`expiration`, '%M %D, %Y') AS formatted_date,
    (@order := @order + 1) AS order_by
FROM
    `alert`
WHERE
    `is_active` = TRUE
ORDER BY
    `expiration`;
```